# ERROR TypeError: this.authService.injectAuthHeaders is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular13

I am getting following error

Issue is i have a abstract class which is not getting injected, i dont know how to inject abstract class.

> looks like the issue is the abstract class AbstractHubService (hub.ts)
> which contain the line
> this.authService.injectAuthHeaders(options.headers);  not injected
> properly. I have given @Injectable({
> providedIn: 'root'   })  But i have not provided that in the app.module.ts and i am unable to provide that in app.module.ts , since
> it is an abstract class, how to inject an abstract class?

```
ERROR TypeError: this.authService.injectAuthHeaders is not a function
at ApisService.options (hub.ts:142:31)
at ApisService.getActivity (apis.service.ts:602:29)
at AppComponent.loadAsyncPageData (app.component.ts:91:13)
at SafeSubscriber._next (page-base.component.ts:50:22)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14:1)
at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42:1)
```

Here is my child class

```
@Injectable ()   
export class ApisService extends AbstractHubService{ 
  private cachedApis: Api[] = null;
 /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param http
     * @param config
     */
  constructor( http: HttpClient,  config: ConfigService,authService: IAuthenticationService) {
    super(http, authService, config);
}
```

Here is my parent abstract class

```
    @Directive({})  
      @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
      })
     export abstract class AbstractHubService {
     
         private apiBaseHref: string;
         private editingBaseHref: string;
         private utilBaseHref: string;
     
         /**
          * Constructor.
          * @param http
          * @param authService
          */
         constructor(protected http: HttpClient, 
            protected authService: IAuthenticationService,
             protected config: ConfigService) {
             this.apiBaseHref = this.config.hubUrl();
             this.editingBaseHref = this.config.editingUrl();
             this.utilBaseHref = this.config.utilUrl();
            
         }

       protected options(headers: {[header: string]: string}, authenticated: boolean = true): any {
         let options = {
             headers: headers
         };
          if (authenticated) {
             this.authService.injectAuthHeaders(options.headers);
         } 
         return options;
     }
```

Here is the interface

```
   @Directive({})
    @Injectable({
    
        providedIn:'root'
    
    })
     export abstract class IAuthenticationService {
 /**
      * Called to inject authentication headers into an API REST call.
      * @param headers
      */
     abstract injectAuthHeaders(headers: {[header: string]: string}): void;
```

This is app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ActivityItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(APP_ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService,ApisService,{provide: 'IAuthenticationService', useClass: ApisService}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The function injectAuthHeaders are defined in three places

[image]

Comment: I may be stupid, but where is `injectAuthHeaders` actually defined in the code you posted? It's mentioned once `this.authService.injectAuthHeaders(options.headers);` ... as if it just has to be there for no apparent reason

Comment: i will post it , its there give me 3 min

Comment: `interface IAuthenticationService` may not feature such method... you assign it with `{provide: 'IAuthenticationService', useClass: ApisService}`, but don't implement a single method of it.

Comment: i updated the interface definition, its there, i also post the definition in 2-3 min

Comment: its an abstract method, i no more definition of it , its there in interface, i updated the question

Comment: abstract injectAuthHeaders(headers: {[header: string]: string}): void;

Comment: still no sign of actual code for that method ... just that abstract definition which isn't code of course ... so ... still no sign that `injectAuthHeaders` is a function

Comment: i have updated the picutre, where it has actual code

Comment: i tried to inject all the above three classes in the search , still the error is there

Comment: looks like the issue is the abstract class AbstractHubService (hub.ts) which contain the line this.authService.injectAuthHeaders(options.headers);  not injected properly. I have given @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })  But i have not provided that in the app.module.ts and i am unable to provide that in app.module.ts , since it is an abstract class, how to inject an abstract class?

Comment: For me, it is very difficult to understand why you chose the implementation the way it is without detailed info about app behavior. You can't use abstract class in `providers` unless you use it with `useClass` or `useExisting`.  I dont think `@Injectable` and `providedIn` should be used for Abstract class.  I also have created abstract class in my app, but I replaced it with `useExisting` with an actual service that had some implementation. Also, with this error it seems like `this.authService` is itself not getting proper instance.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i fixed the error since i also have the code flow in place here. The issue was auth-keyclock.service.ts was calling a provider AuthenticationServiceProvider and this provider was not injected, i injected the AuthenticationServiceProvider and issues is solved!  AuthenticationServiceProvider i added in the provider section of app.module.ts solved the issue. Thanks for all the support!